# Problem with FMU models and Operating System

Tags: python, model, simulink, binaries

From what I understand and I have read, FMU models are the best option to work with models across different platforms, operating systems...etc. However I have a problem.

I have a FMU model (exported to .fmu from simulink on my windowsx64 operating system) and when I try to open it in python (with pyfmi library) on my windowsx64 computer I do it without problem. However, when I try to open that same model in python on my mac computer, I can't do it, returning this error:

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidBinaryException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 10
      7 fmu_path = './prueba13/sldemo_bounce13.fmu'
      9 # Cargar la FMU
---> 10 model = load_fmu(fmu_path)

File src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx:8822, in pyfmi.fmi.load_fmu()

File src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx:7062, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelCS2.__init__()

File src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx:4169, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelBase2.__init__()

InvalidBinaryException: The FMU could not be loaded. Error loading the binary. The FMU contains no binary for this platform.
```

Is there any way to work with FMU models from different operating systems or you can only work with FMUs with the same operating system with which it has been created? Is there any way of working in python with FMU models that came from other Operating Systems?. According to the theory on the internet, the FMU format is the best way to work with models between different systems, so I understand that the problem I have should be overcome.

Thank you very much in advance,

I tried:

- explored different ways of exporting the model
- explored all I could of pyfmi library
- tried in different computers and versions

I expect that someone with more familiarity that me with FMUs can shed some light on this issue.